# How can I narrow down my soup.find search to one line in the HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape one line of html from this:

```
<strong class="listingPrice">
    £75- £85
    <abbr title="">pw</abbr>
</strong>
```

The line I'm trying to scrape is "`£75- £85`"

My current code to scrape the page is:

```
html_text = requests.get("web address").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
prices = soup.find_all('strong', class_='listingPrice')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents[0]`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


doc = """<strong class="listingPrice">
    £75- £85
    <abbr title="">pw</abbr>
</strong>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")

price = soup.select_one(".listingPrice").contents[0].strip()
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
£75- £85
```

---

Or `.find_next()` with `text=True`:

```
price = soup.select_one(".listingPrice").find_next(text=True).strip()
```

Comment: Another way `soup.select_one(".listingPrice").next_element.strip()`.